# Cassandra Stress - Limit items in the List Data Type

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress, cassandra-stress-tool

Using cassandra-stress for benchmarking.

Is there any support to limit number of items in the list?

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace1.users (
username text,
user_fav_movies list,
PRIMARY KEY (username)
```

Cassandra-stress table user profile:

```
name: user_fav_movies
size: fixed(10)
)
```

`fixed/population` does not help to limit number of items in the list

Comment: Look to github.com/nosqlbench instead